# How to get rid of out of context references in Solidworks?

Tags: solidworks

I got some sketches to have questionmarks.

I found, that it means "Out-of-context external reference"

I don't understand what it means and wish to get rid of it.

Repair does nothing, rebuild works fine. Although, I can't insert my part into new assempbly.

[image]

If I click either "Break All" or "Lock all", I get my part broken.

Can't I just reinterpret any external relation as local and get rid of it?

Suppose we take `Plane1 -> ?`

[image]

It is probably referencing assembly, that I have deleted. Can I fix this situation in any way?

---

My `Plane1` is at known distance from plane `Top`, but shifted. If I start to edit it, I am getting it rotated or otherwise moved. How to define such a location?

[image]

Comment: Again, your question isn't great - you've asked how to "get rid of" the out of context reference. Do you mean "get rid of the error - i.e. have the reference made to be in context" or "get rid of the reference".

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that it has do with the assembly you deleted. Basically, you connected a constraint in your part with a feature in another part/assembly.

While this is useful for designing (essential for a top down approach), it can lead to problems like the one you are describing. Normally the procedure is to :

- Break the external reference
- Remove the external reference.

See the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HS01FDzp_U) for an example, when the assembly already exist.

One key point is **not** to rebuild your part.